# Placing points on a line to achieve base-lines of 1, 2, 3, 4...

Tags: geometry

In a field like radio astronomy, it is useful to place radio telescopes on a line so that there are pairs of telescopes at consecutive distances 1, 2, 3, 4, 5....

Consider 5 radio telescopes as points on the x-axis as follows: A (x=0), B (x=4), C (x=5), D (x=7), E (x=13).

This arrangement has inter-point distances of 1 (BC), 2 (CD), 3 (BD), 4 (AB), 5 (AC), 6 (DE), 7 (AD), 8 (CE), 9 (BE).  There is also a base line of 13 (AE) that isn't needed.

Here's my open-ended question:  a) For a given sequence of base line distances 1, 2, 3, 4....n, is there a way to know MINIMUM number of points needed to achieve those base lines?   b) Is there an algorithm to give the actual arrangement of points?

Comment: keyphrase: Golomb ruler.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: [Perfect ruler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_ruler) looks even more appropriate, according to Wikipedia. But the definitions on [Peter Luschny's page](http://www.luschny.de/math/rulers/introe.html) require a perfect ruler to be complete, which is not implied by the OP.

Comment: Both the Golomb ruler and the Perfect Ruler pointed me in the right direction.